# Add back button / navigation button on sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to insert buttons for navigation on a site using SharePoint Online. Basically, I have a series of folders with subfolders and files, and I would like to be able to browse in a similar file-explorer style, so I would like to put the following:

- a simple "up" button to go to the previous level and
- a "home" button. The home button is also quite easy (just create a link and direct it to the home site).

But I can't figure out how to create the "up" (or back) button. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can Click to edit you SharePoint home screen, and then click to add Webpart
From the list of web parts choose 'button'.